# prevent email-2-case from creating new cases

Tags: email2case

Is there any way to prevent email2Case from creating new cases?

While i need the functionality of all emails being tracked on an already existing case, but i dont want the functionality of new cases being created when the threadId is absent.

If anyone has a suggestion that involves getting rid of email2case altogether, it is also acceptable. At the end of the day, i need the ability to track all emails on a case, but dont want new cases to be created via emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com

This involves writing custom code to handle inbound email services ( that means getting rid of out of the box email2case). If you implement custom code you will have lot of flexibility over normal email2case.

Comment: Thanks Manjunath. Yes i was planning to go that route, but wanted to see if anyone has some unique ideas. I was also thinking about writing a before-insert trigger on case to filter those cases out and prevent their creation.

Comment: I think trigger is quicker solution !

Answer (score 0):

If you use the thread of in your subjectand body, duplicates shouldn'tbe created. You might want to replace the send email button on the related list with a custom button that auto adds the thread id in both places to keep new emails in sync too

Comment: MeighanRocksSF - Issue is not when the emails are sent from salesforce to a customer ... email2case automatically embeds a threadId in there. But if a customer responds (or composes a new email) to the salesforce routing address, and accidentally deletes threadId (or if its a new email, there wont be any threadID), the email2case functionality creates a case. Thats the part i want to prevent.